# Server responded with 404: Not Found for localhost/undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been scratching my head for days. I've googled to no avail. I am trying to get stuff from a database with jquery.ajax, based on the information I send over (sorta a post AND a get) everytime though, the server responds with an `Error 404: Not Found`, and is telling me I asked for `Localhost:1986/undefined`, which is not the case.

I'm sure exactly where all my folders and files are is important, so I will include as much as I can, feel free to ask for more if it is necessary.

My script is copy pasted and modified from another script I have to post to the database, and that works fine, so why this one doesn't stumps me:

```
function nextSlide() {
    var articleLink = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../SlideShow/NextArticle",
        data: {
            slideID: articleLink.getAttribute("id"),
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $(articleLink).id = result[0];
            document.getElementById("articleImage").setAttribute("src", result[1]);
            document.getElementById("articleTitle").innerHTML = result[2];
            document.getElementById("articleText").innerHTML = result[3];
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the method inside my `SlideShowController.cs` file I am trying to use:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult NextArticle(string slideID)
{
    int ID = int.Parse(slideID);
    var articles = db.Slides.ToList();
    var currentArticle = db.Slides.First(s => s.SlideId == ID);
    int articlePosition = articles.IndexOf(currentArticle);
    articlePosition = (articlePosition + 1) >= articles.Count() ? 0 : articlePosition + 1;

    var nextArticle = articles.ElementAt(articlePosition);
    //nextArticle.Article.ArticleText.Substring(0, 50)+"..."
    string[] returnParameters = { 
                                    nextArticle.SlideId.ToString(),
                                    nextArticle.Image.ImageURL,
                                    nextArticle.Article.ArticleTitle,
                                    nextArticle.Article.ArticleText
                                };
    return Json(returnParameters);
}
```

The `SlideShowController.cs` file is inside a folder named `Controllers` in the root directory. The script is called from a `_SlideShowPartial.cshtml` file in a `Root/Views/SlideShow` folder. That file is loaded in a `Index.cshtml` file in a `Root/Views/Home` folder using `@html.Partial()`

Here is a screenshot of the error that appears in chrome console:
[image]

And here is the contents of the Web.Config file inside the `Views` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"     type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup,     System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host"     type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection,     System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages"     type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection,     System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc,     Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="TIAWebWorkConnect.Models.AppViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to     occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter,     System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc,     Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: remove those `..` from `../SlideShow/NextArticle` and check.

Comment: @HarveySpecter it still throws the same error, also nice username, suits

Comment: Haha. Thanks. Finally, someone who recognizes. If you can just try try removing this : `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)]` and put this : `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @HarveySpecter That throws the same error aswell

Comment: Does this hit at the controller or throws the error int he ajax call itself ? Also, is it hosted online or your are using localhost right now ?

Comment: Please post full controller code, web.config and maybe screen from some console in browser where this error is visible.

Comment: @HarveySpecter@Kamo I am using localhost, I doesn't hit the controller at all, I have a breakpoint set. That is the full controller code, I will post the contents of web.config and an image of the error

Comment: @user3189142 - When you run your project on localhost, what port number does it show in the browser URL ?

Comment: @HarveySpecter it shows 1986 as the port number

Comment: Double check on your `Route.config` for any route settings that you have applied which could come in the way of this.

Comment: @HarveySpecter There's no `Route.config`, we do have a `RouteConfig.cs` which I believe is the same thing, no? It's just this one controller that can't be accessed for some reason, another Controller I have no issues with using jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely sending url wrongly to the server. try a complete url, or remove url from your $.ajax query.

Answer (score 0):

Consider introducing T4 MVC into your project. This will give you strongly typed access to MVC actions and let you avoid URL strings which looks like your issue here.

https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/blob/master/README.md